# Custom TouchableOpacity from Pressable TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, react-native, touchableopacity, pressable

Have this custom TouchableOpacity function component, but for the style prop I'm getting a TS error

```
import { StyleSheet, Pressable, PressableProps, GestureResponderEvent } from 'react-native';

export default function TouchableOpacity(props: PressableProps) {
  const { style, onPress, children } = props;

  return (
    <Pressable
      onPress={(event: GestureResponderEvent) => {
        onPress?.(event);
      }}
      style={({ pressed }) => [style, pressed ? styles.buttonPressedOpacity : null]}>
      {children}
    </Pressable>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonPressedOpacity: {
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
});
```

Here is the complete TS complaint:

> TS2322: Type '({ pressed }: PressableStateCallbackType) =>
> (StyleProp | ((state: PressableStateCallbackType) =>
> StyleProp<...>) | { ...; })[]' is not assignable to type
> 'StyleProp | ((state: PressableStateCallbackType) =>
> StyleProp)'.   Type '({ pressed }:
> PressableStateCallbackType) => (StyleProp | ((state:
> PressableStateCallbackType) => StyleProp<...>) | { ...; })[]' is not
> assignable to type '(state: PressableStateCallbackType) =>
> StyleProp'.     Type '(StyleProp | ((state:
> PressableStateCallbackType) => StyleProp) | { opacity:
> number; })[]' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp'.
>       Type '(StyleProp | ((state: PressableStateCallbackType) => StyleProp) | { opacity:
> number; })[]' is not assignable to type 'RecursiveArray<ViewStyle |
> Falsy | RegisteredStyle>'.         The types returned by
> 'pop()' are incompatible between these types.           Type
> 'StyleProp | ((state: PressableStateCallbackType) =>
> StyleProp) | { opacity: number; }' is not assignable to
> type 'ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle |
> RecursiveArray<ViewStyle | Falsy | RegisteredStyle> |
> readonly (ViewStyle | ... 1 more ... | RegisteredStyle<...>)[]'.
>             Type '(state: PressableStateCallbackType) => StyleProp' is not assignable to type 'ViewStyle | Falsy |
> RegisteredStyle | RecursiveArray<ViewStyle | Falsy |
> RegisteredStyle> | readonly (ViewStyle | ... 1 more ... |
> RegisteredStyle<...>)[]'.  index.d.ts(542, 5): The expected type comes
> from property 'style' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & PressableProps & RefAttributes'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is the type of `style` which is received from `PressableProps` and its concatination with the function you provide to the `style` prop of `Pressable`.  The type of `style` is as follows:

```js
const style: StyleProp<ViewStyle> | ((state: PressableStateCallbackType) => StyleProp<ViewStyle>)
```

The style is either `StyleProp<ViewStyle>` **or** a function that receives a `PressableStateCallbackType` as an input parameter.

However, the type of the `style` prop of `Pressable` is as follows:

```js
PressableProps.style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle> | ((state: PressableStateCallbackType) => StyleProp<ViewStyle>)
```

Thus, the following would work:

```js
<Pressable
  style={style}>
</Pressable>
```

Since the types match.

However, if you provide the function that receives `PressableStateCallbackType` yourself and you want to combine this with an additional style, then you have two possibilities.

**You know that `style` is indeed the mentioned function**

```js
const _style = style as (pressed: PressableStateCallbackType) => StyleProp<ViewStyle>

<Pressable   
  style={(state) => [_style(state), state.pressed && styles.buttonPressedOpacity]}>
</Pressable>
```

**You know that `style` is a `StyleProp<ViewStyle>`**

```js
<Pressable
  style={({pressed}) => [style as StyleProp<ViewStyle>, pressed && styles.buttonPressedOpacity]}>
</Pressable>
```

**You do not know**

```js
<Pressable
  style={(state) => [typeof style === 'function' ? style(state) : style, state.pressed && styles.buttonPressedOpacity]}>
</Pressable>
```

**Edit:** Actually, if you know the type and it is your custom component, then you could change the typing of the props of `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: Thanks! using You do not know option worked, I basically want a TouchableOpacity but using the Pressable component